# Generate links with token

Tags: angular, inheritance, jwt, url-parameters, angular6

In Angular 6, I would like to retrieve a JWT token from the URL, convert it to base 64 and push it to some other links.

I did this:

*app-routing.module.ts*:

```ts
{ path: 'admin/:token', redirectTo: 'admin/:token/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

*app.component.ts*:

```ts
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

// JWT TEST TOKEN
// eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c

_token: string = null;
public get Token(): string { return this._token; }
public set Token(value: string) { this._token = value; }


constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute,
            public router: Router) {

    console.log("## App started! ##");

    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        let _token: string = params['token'];
        console.log(_token);
        console.log(this.encodeToken(_token));

        this.Token = this.encodeToken(_token); //btoa(_token);
    });

}

ngOnInit(callback?: () => void) {

}

public encodeToken(token:string) {
    return encodeURI(btoa(token)).replace(/=/g, "#");
}

public decodeToken(codedToken: string) {
    return decodeURI(atob(codedToken.replace(/#/g, "=")));
}
}
```

*app.component.html*:

```html
<div style="margin: 1em;">
<sui-tabset>
    <div class="ui pointing secondary menu">
        <a class="item" routerLink="/admin/{{Token}}/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
        <a class="item" routerLink="/admin/{{Token}}/report">Reporting</a>
        <a class="item" routerLink="/admin/{{Token}}/stats">Stats</a>            
    </div>
</sui-tabset>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

*dashboard.component.ts*:

```ts
export class DashboardComponent extends AppComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute,
    public router: Router) {

    super(route, router);
}

ngOnInit() {        
    console.log(this.Token);
}

}
```

And yet, the based64 token in my URL doesn't correspond to the converted token displayed in my console.log from dashboard.
The links look like this:

```ts
http://localhost:4200/admin/dW5kZWZpbmVk/dashboard
```

Expected token:

```ts
ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5LmV5SnpkV0lpT2lJeE1qTTBOVFkzT0Rrd0lpd2libUZ0WlNJNklrcHZhRzRnUkc5bElpd2lhV0YwSWpveE5URTJNak01TURJeWZRLlNmbEt4d1JKU01lS0tGMlFUNGZ3cE1lSmYzNlBPazZ5SlZfYWRRc3N3NWM#
```

I'm doubting myself about the inheritance of AppComponent in dashboard.component.ts. Is it best practice to do for retrieving info from URL? Is there another method? Still didn't find any valuable doc on this.

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

[UPDATE]

As it seems I can't get the route parameters in the AppComponent, a working solution is to place the navigation in each sub component.
I don't like this solution but it will do the job for now.

Comment: It is not a good practise to pass such tokens in url params. Can't you use a service to preserve the token?

Comment: There is no token in your URL, "dW5kZWZpbmVk" is the base64 version of "undefined"

Comment: I agree but these are the specs I have to deal with. What kind of service are your talking about? (i'm rather new to angular)

Comment: @jps How could I have an undefined in the URL and the component.html displays the correct token? Is it because I do the convert in the constructor?

Comment: @jps It seems I can't get the route parameters in the AppComponent. So an easy and working solution would be to move the navigation section in a separate component and inject it into EACH component ... which is not very sexy. Tell me there is another way :)

Comment: A better solution would be to  put the token into the http header with `new HttpHeaders().set('X-Remote-JWT', Token)` but I understand you are not able to go for this solution due to other restrictions.

Comment: @MatthiasSommer indeed, there are some restrictions I can't go against.